# Multi-Editing in Notepad++ select surrounding words

Tags: notepad++

I have Notepad++ 6.7.8.2.

I have enabled Multi-Editing. When I control-click on a second location close to a word, this word got selected, and this will happen for any further location selection. Any multi-edition will then delete the selected words. (c.f. attached file for a screenshot of the selection)
[image: Selection during multi-Editing]

Any idea on how to solve this?

I am currently using SublimeText when I need to do a multi-edition... which is not very convenient (the switching, not SublimeText which is awesome by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have found out that this is a conflict between **Multi-Editing** and the an option of the plugin **Source Cookifier** which is set by default: "*Go to definition by pressing ctrl + left mousebutton*".

Unchecking this option will solve the problem.